# MySQL combining complex queries and optimizing functionality

Tags: php, mysql, join, mysqli, left-join

I have a fairly complicated notification system that I am working on, it's quite simple for the most part, the complexity gets into checking other tables whether or not the content has been removed or not, and I have multiple tables of data that all goes into the notification system, so it has to check each of those, and I have to be able to easily be able to add more tables as I build the website to allow other notification types to be added, and with the current query i am using it does not allow that, I have tried to come up with a better way of doing this, however I am not good enough with mysql queries to do so, so I am hoping I could get some (or it may turn out to be alot) of assistance by one (or some) of you.

Here's my current query:

```
SELECT
    n.*,
    MIN(n.state) state,
    MIN(n.status) status,
    MAX(n.date) maxDate
FROM notifications n
LEFT JOIN comments c 
     ON n.type = 'comment' 
     AND n.uniqueID = c.id  
     AND c.state='0'
LEFT JOIN posts p 
     ON n.type = 'post' 
     AND p.id = n.uniqueID OR n.type = 'comment' 
     AND p.id = c.postID

WHERE n.toID = '$session'
AND p.state = 0
GROUP BY n.uniqueID
ORDER BY status ASC, maxDate DESC
```

So what the above statement does, in a nutshell, is this. It selects notifications from the notification table, in this table there is a column for `type` and `uniqueID` of that content. So for each row that's type is `posts` it checks the post table where the `uniqueID` from notifications is the same as the unique id in the posts table, which it then checks the `state` of that post to see if it has been deleted or not (if it has not been removed, state=0, else I don't want it). The same goes for comments.

So I need a way to do everything just like this does it, however I need it to be easier to continuously add new table checks to it. I have been trying to add another left join for a table called likes, however i am unable to get it to work together, for whatever reason. However I have come up with this code that will do what I want it to. (only for the likes table though, it does not include any other table which i need it to)

```
SELECT
    n.*,
    MIN(n.state) state,
    MIN(n.status) status,
    MAX(n.date) maxDate
FROM notifications n
LEFT JOIN likes l 
     ON n.type = 'likes' 
     AND n.uniqueID = l.id 
WHERE n.toID = '$session'
AND l.state='0'
GROUP BY n.uniqueID
ORDER BY status ASC, maxDate DESC
```

I hope someone can help me out with this solution, thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In looks like you could use an "ANY" subquery
 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html

```
SELECT
    n.*,
    MIN(n.state) state,
    MIN(n.status) status,
    MAX(n.date) maxDate
FROM notifications n
WHERE n.toID = '$session' AND
    (
        (
            n.type = 'likes' AND
            n.uniqueID = ANY (
                SELECT likes.id
                FROM likes INNER JOIN posts on (likes.postId=posts.id)
                WHERE likes.state='0' and posts.state='0'
            )
        ) OR
        (
            n.type = 'comment' AND
            n.uniqueID = ANY (
                SELECT comments.id
                FROM comments INNER JOIN posts on (comments.postId=posts.id)
                WHERE comments.state='0' and posts.state='0'
            )
        ) OR
        (
            n.type = 'post' AND
            n.uniqueID = ANY (SELECT id FROM posts WHERE state='0')
        )
    )
GROUP BY n.uniqueID
ORDER BY status ASC, maxDate DESC;
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much! This so far seems to be working just about how it should, I am going to continue testing out everything to make sure it is, but this definitely seems like it will be what I have been looking for!

Comment: I have found one thing.For these particular 3 types of notifications, if the post's state is not equal to 0, then it shouldnt show that notification. So if there is a like, and a comment on post with the ID of 36,as long as the state of the post (in the posts table) is 0, it must show,however if the state changes to,in this case,1, it shouldn't show the comment or like notification for that post. in comments and likes table,I have a column called "postID",so for instance,the n.type='comment' one,should also check posts table and find the post with that id to make sure state is 0,same for likes

Comment: So the 'state' is part of the posts rather then the likes/comments tables?  If so, could change the 'likes' subquery to be (SELECT likes.id FROM likes INNER JOIN posts on (likes.postId=posts.id) where posts.state='0')

Comment: Well, the 'state' is part of each table, so that check does have to be done for each one, as for any notification type the state can change from 0 to 1, so how you have it right now is absolutely how it needs to check it, however, in addition to those, for likes and comments type's, it has to check the posts table for which post the like and comment is attributed with, because if the post has been removed (the state changed from 0 to 1), those notifications shouldn't be shown. However, I will be adding notification types that will not be attributed directly to the posts table's, so it...

Comment: Can't really be an absolute check for the entire query, but like how you have it right now, on a per type basis.

Comment: Added a bit to the subqueries, but don't have test data handy to verify it.

Comment: Actually nevermind! Your code above is perfect, it was mine that had a missing "AND" from one part, it works beautifully now! This is brilliant, thank you sir!